# how to make higher jumps in a SASS for loop

Tags: for-loop, sass

i want my scss for loop to jump be 15 every time its loops over.
I found the following a code on stack, but in my css input its just jumps by 1 like a 1000 times.

The  css output i want:

```
#planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--15:checked ~ 
label[for="radio--0--0"] {
  background: #8FE501;
  color: #111; }

#planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--30:checked ~ 
label[for="radio--0--0"] {
  background: #8FE501;
  color: #111; }

#planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--45:checked ~ 
label[for="radio--0--0"] {
  background: #8FE501;
  color: #111; }


#planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--1--0:checked ~ 
label[for="radio--0--0"] {
  background: #8FE501;
  color: #111; }

#planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--1--15:checked ~ 
label[for="radio--0--0"] {
  background: #8FE501;
  color: #111; }
```

etc.......

the output i now get:

```
  #planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--0:checked ~ 
  label[for="radio--0--0"] {
    background: #8FE501;
    color: #111; }

  #planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--1:checked ~ 
  label[for="radio--0--1"] {
    background: #8FE501;
    color: #111; }

  #planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--2:checked ~ 
  label[for="radio--0--2"] {
    background: #8FE501;
    color: #111; }

 #planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--3:checked ~ 
 label[for="radio--0--3"] {
    background: #8FE501;
    color: #111; }

 #planningStudent #planningGrid #radio--0--4:checked ~ 
 label[for="radio--0--4"] {
   background: #8FE501;
   color: #111; }
```

etc...

Here is the scss for Loop i used;

Anny help will be great!
Thanks!

```
    $max: 60 * 24;
    $step: 15;
    @for $y from 0 through 4 {
        @for $x from 0 through ceil($max/$step) {
            #radio--#{$y}--#{$x}:checked ~ label[for="radio--#{$y}--#{$x}"] {
                background: $glr-green;
                color: #111;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's a little hard to determine what you're trying to do.

Here's a [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/0ab93acf7890476e38d862e78332eb76) based on these criteria:

- `:checked` radio--0--0 is ignored
- `:checked` radio 1st number, starting at 0, increments by 1
- `:checked` radio last number increments by 15
- label to always be `label[for="radio--0--0"]`

The if/else is a little hacky, but does the job.

```
$glr-green: #8FE501;

@for $y from 0 through 3 {
  @for $x from 0 through 3 {
    @if ($y == 0 and $x == 0) { /* FOGEDABOUDIT */ }
    @else {
      #radio--#{$y}--#{$x * 15}:checked ~ label[for="radio--0--0"] {
          background: $glr-green;
          color: #111;
      }
    }
  }
}
```